# Mover Div para Cima com Jquery

Tags: jquery, formulário

Oi, eu tenho uma configuração de divs em um crud e queria colocar a div que eu crio dinamicamente acima de uma UL que contém os botões de enviar. Não é possível colocar isso manualmente via html pois a tela é gerada automaticamente via JFormer. Eu queria colocar as divs "campos" pra cima da UL "JFormerControl"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

via jquery eu não consigo.

```
$(".jFormerControl").append('.campos');
$(".campos").append(".jFormerControl");
```

Eu tentei por esses comandos mas não rolou. Alguém já passou por isso e pode me ajudar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta algo assim:

```
var $campos = $(".campos");
var $formerControl = $(".jFormerControl");
$formerControl.append($campos);
```

Comment: agora ficou dentro da div, mas o UL ainda fica por primeiro :|

Comment: Pra ficar antes de qualquer outro elemento use o "preppend".

Comment: uso então $formerControl.preppend($campos); ?

Comment: Isso. Apenas corrigindo, é "prepend" com apenas um p. http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Comment: Funcionou aqui, valeu (: